# Determine attribute being tested in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I have a massive validate function in my backbone model that could be simplified if only I could detect the attribute I'm testing against. There are a few ideas of how I can think to approach this problem, but they all rely on knowing the attribute name I'm testing, without hardcoding it as I am in the `id` variable below.

## Here is an example:

```
validate : function(attr){
    var t = this;
    
    if(attr.user1DobMonth && attr.user1DobMonth != t.get('user1DobMonth')){
         var val = jQuery.trim(attr.user1DobMonth.toLowerCase()),
         id = 'user1DobMonth',
             
         error = {
            attr : id
         };
        
         if(val === 'select'){
            return error;
         }
    }
    if(attr.user2DobMonth && attr.user2DobMonth != t.get('user2DobMonth')){
        var val = jQuery.trim(attr.user2DobMonth.toLowerCase()),
            id = 'user2DobMonth',

            error = {
                attr : id
            };

        if(val === 'select'){
            return error;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, `detect`? Can you iterate over all of the attributes, or for the example you gave, why not use a loop over the two attributes.

Comment: validation in backbone is a completely undefined area of the framework. The way I'm doing it is one of multitude of ways of doing it. By detect, I mean that I can test if an attribute matches the `if()` block, but if I match two `attr` in the same `if()`, then I don't know which one I'm dealing with.